# Logical Address in 2 level paging

Tags: operating-system, paging

Consider a system using 2 level paging.Page table is divided into 2K pages each of size 4 KW. The page table entry size is 2W.  If PAS is 64 MW which is divided into 16K frames. Memory is word addressable,Calculate length of Logical Address (LA), Physical Address(PA),Outer Page Table Size (OPTS)and Inner Page Table Size (IPTS).

What I did -

```
PAS=64MW= 2^26 
Thus,PA=26 Bits

LAS = Page Size* No. of Pages * Page Table Entry Size  
    = 4KW * 2K * 2W
    = 2^23
Thus LA=23 bits.
```

The answer are as follows :

```
1.LA=35 bits

2.PA=26 bits

3.OPTS=4KW

4.IPTS=8KW
```

I can't make out how did LA becomes 35 bits instead of 22 bits. How is LA distributed in terms of P1,P2 & d ? Can someone help me ?

Comment: This question is nonsensical. I could go through a litany of problems, I'll just do one: The length of a physical address is entirely system specific and cannot be calculated from this kind of data. I never cease to be amazed at the useless questions inflicted on CS students.

Comment: It should be 34 and not 35. The 35 answer is wrong.

Comment: @user3344003 Just a taste of theoretical OS.

Comment: It's not theoretical. Page tables are data structures. This kind of exercise does nothing to help learn about how they work and, in fact, is more misleading than helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size of `page` = `4KW` = `2^12 W`. This means that `offset(d)` is `12 bits`.

Let us assume that `LAS(logical address space)` consist of total `2^x` pages. Because it is `2 level paging`, we have

```
((2^x)*2)/(size of 1 page) = 2K pages
```

This means that `2^(x + 1 - 12) = 2^(11)`. Therefore, we have `x = 22`. Hence, the logical address space = `22 + 12` = `34` `bits`